# CGBitmapContextCreate memory release responsibility

Tags: ios, memory-management, cgbitmapcontext

This is how I create a `UIImage`. I allocated `piOutData` with calloc. Now when I call `CGImageRelease` at the end, will it automatically release `piOutData` or I need to do it manually via free.

```
int m_iH = iInMaxDim;
int m_iW = iInMaxDim;

UInt8*piOutData = calloc(iInMaxDim *iInMaxDim*4,sizeof(UInt8));
CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(piOutData,  
                                         m_iW,  
                                         m_iH,  
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(inImage.CGImage),
                                         m_iW*4,  
                                         CGImageGetColorSpace(inImage.CGImage),  
                                         CGImageGetBitmapInfo(inImage.CGImage) 
                                         ); 
CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);  
CGContextRelease(ctx);
UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> …when I call CGImageRelease at the end, will it automatically release piOutData?

No. `piOutData` is owned by you.